# (Solved) Quick double integral question

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

I am doing a probability course and I completely forgot integration, it's been 10 years... Anyway, I am after a helpful hint, not just the answer. I've gotten from:

$$\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^\infty e^{-(x+y)} \, dxdy $$

To this:

$$\int_{0}^\infty -\frac{1}{1+y}e^{-y} dy $$

I am not sure if I've done the first integration correctly, but if I have, a hint or a push in the right direction would be greatly appreciate

**(Please just give a useful hint, not the answer. It feels better when I can work through it. Thanks)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x-y}dxdy = \left(\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}dx\right)^2$